# How to Retrieve data based on user not on device

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I am able to see data that is saved on a particular mobile. If I log in on different devices using the same username password then data is not available there.

Following code written in DBHelper.java

```
public List<String> getSampleItem(){
        Cursor cursor=null;
        List<String> sampleItemList=new ArrayList<>();
        sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();            
        Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_PROCUREMENT,new String[]strong text{DB_COLUMN_SAMPLE_ITEM},null,null,null,null,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                sampleItemList.add(cursor.getString(0));

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return sampleItemList;

    }
```

Calling from Activity.java

```
private void prepareProcurementData(){
        ProcurementData procurementData= null;
        for (int i=0;i<dbHelper.getSampleItem().size();i++) {
            procurementData = new ProcurementData(dbHelper.getDate().get(i),dbHelper.getSampleItem().get(i));
            procurementDataList.add(procurementData);
        }   


        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database and therefore the data within is specific to the device. SQlite has no inbuilt client/server/cloud functionaility.

It sounds like that SQlite may not be suitable for your requirements, perhaps Firebase could be.

You may wish to have a read of [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It means the data which I have saved locally I cannot access that data on another mobile. For that purpose, I have to save data on server.Then only I can access data on any mobile. Am I write?

Comment: @Swati It's not that you can't rather it would be complicated i.e. you'd have to create the client server functionaility and then more as there would be a good chance that you would have to cope with a distributed database (i.e. the is no single point of collaboration as such). So saving the data on a single server with multiple clients would very likely be the simplest solution.